# How do I use SetTimer() to create certain number of message boxes after another in c++?

Tags: c++, messagebox

I am trying to make it so when a messagebox opens another one opens a couple seconds later without any user input (pressing the OK button). I want the old one to stay open, but a new one to appear. I also want to be able to use `SetWindowsHookEx` and set a limit on how many message boxes are created. I know this uses the function SetTimer() and needs some kind of if statement with the current number of dialogs that equal the limit and stop when the number is reached. So how do I make this work? I tried to research, but nothing seemed to work.

My attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

thread_local int MsgBox_X;
thread_local int MsgBox_Y;
thread_local int Limit = 10;

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        CBT_CREATEWND* s = (CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam;
        if (s->lpcs->hwndParent == NULL)
        {
            s->lpcs->x = MsgBox_X;
            s->lpcs->y = MsgBox_Y;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &CBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    MsgBox_X = X;
    MsgBox_Y = Y;
    int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    if (hHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return result;
if (<# of dialogs> == Limit) {
    std::terminate()
    }
}

void _MessageBox()
{
    HWND HWND1;
    MessageBox(HWND1, TEXT("Message"), TEXT("MsgBox"), MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
    SetTimer(HWND1, 
        TIMER1,
        2000,
        (TIMERPROC)NULL);
    case WM_TIMER:

        switch (wParam)
        {
        case TIMER1:
            MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Message 2"), TEXT("MsgBox 2"), MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK, 50, 50);

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    _MessageBox();
}
```

Comment: Side note: it is good idea to write question in such a way that it is not obvious that you are creating prank/malware... In addition to having [mre] of coding problem or otherwise showing your research on the subject.

Comment: Any chance of showing your actual code? The above is clearly not able to be compiled. We prefer problems to puzzles...

Comment: There. Minimal code that is compliable if you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an *uninitialized* `HWND` to `MessageBox()`.

Also, `MessageBox()` is a blocking function, it doesn't exit until the dialog is closed, so you need to create the timer *before* you call `MessageBox()`. Unless you use `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()` to hook the creation of the dialog, then you can create the timer when the dialog's `HWND` is created, and you pass that `HWND` to `SetTimer()`.

Also, your syntax to handle the `WM_TIMER` message is just plain wrong.

That being said, `MessageBox()` displays a modal dialog and runs its own message loop, so you don't need to handle `WM_TIMER` manually at all. You can assign a callback to the timer, and let the modal loop dispatch the callback events for you.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

thread_local int MsgBox_X;
thread_local int MsgBox_Y;
thread_local int NumMsgBoxes = 0;

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTSetPosProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        CBT_CREATEWND* s = (CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam;
        if (s->lpcs->hwndParent == NULL)
        {
            s->lpcs->x = MsgBox_X;
            s->lpcs->y = MsgBox_Y;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &CBTSetPosProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    MsgBox_X = X;
    MsgBox_Y = Y;
    int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    if (hHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return result;
}

static void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD)
{
    if (NumMsgBoxes > 0)
    {
        --NumMsgBoxes;
        MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Message 2"), TEXT("MsgBox 2"), MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK, 50, 50);
    }
}

void _MessageBox(int NumberOfMsgBoxes)
{
    NumMsgBoxes = NumberOfMsgBoxes;
    if (NumMsgBoxes > 0)
    {
        --NumMsgBoxes;
        UINT timer = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 2000, &TimerProc);
        if (timer) {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Message"), TEXT("MsgBox"), MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
            KillTimer(NULL, timer);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    _MessageBox(5);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <Windows.h>

thread_local int MsgBox_X;
thread_local int MsgBox_Y;
thread_local int NumMsgBoxes = 0;

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTSetPosProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        CBT_CREATEWND* s = (CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam;
        if (s->lpcs->hwndParent == NULL)
        {
            s->lpcs->x = MsgBox_X;
            s->lpcs->y = MsgBox_Y;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &CBTSetPosProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    MsgBox_X = X;
    MsgBox_Y = Y;
    int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    if (hHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return result;
}

static void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT_PTR idTimer, DWORD dwTime)
{
    KillTimer(hwnd, idTimer);
    if (NumMsgBoxes > 0)
        MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("Message 2"), TEXT("MsgBox 2"), MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK, 50, 50);
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTSetTimerProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        CBT_CREATEWND* s = (CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam;
        if (s->lpcs->hwndParent == NULL)
        {
            if (--NumMsgBoxes > 0)
                SetTimer((HWND)wParam, 1, 2000, &TimerProc);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void _MessageBox(int NumberOfMsgBoxes)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &CBTSetTimerProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    NumMsgBoxes = NumberOfMsgBoxes;
    if (NumMsgBoxes > 0)
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Message"), TEXT("MsgBox"), MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
    if (hHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
}

int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    _MessageBox(5);
}
```

Comment: How would it be different if you used ```SetWindowsHookEx()```? Also, how do I set when it stops creating messageboxes?

Comment: I updated my code. May you update yours for ``SetWindowsHookEx```?

Comment: You already know how to use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to determine the `HWND` of the `MessageBox` dialog.  You can use that same `HWND` with `SetTimer()`. As for stopping the creation of `MessageBox`es, well you already know how to use thread-local variables, so simply define another variable that holds the desired dialog count and then stop when you reach that many dialogs, or define a flag variable that is set to true on any other condition you want, and then stop creating dialogs when that flag is set.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm probably bothering you now, but you think I know what I'm doing and I really don't. I'm just a beginner that barely knows anything. For one the code with ```SetWindowsHookEx``` I actually borrowed from you. Again I've tried and tried to figure this out on my own. I noticed ```SetWinEventHook()`` has EVENT_MAX, but only the HookEX method works at all in my code. I defined another variable, but I don't know how I should make the if statement. I don't know what to put in for how many current dialogs and what to put to make it stop.

Comment: @ThrownRedstone then please edit your question to include more details about your actual end goal, and I will consider updating my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should've known better. I've edited my question.